# Flask - fetching files from a subdirectory of main upload folder

Tags: python, web, flask

On my app I am trying to return files that have been previously uploaded by users. I have one big upload folder and some files are within subfolders of that folder. How might I return files located in these subdirectories? For files not in subfolders this works fine:

```
@app.route ('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_image(filename): 
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

However for one in a subfolder of the upload folder I tried

```
@app.route('/uploads/<new_folder_name>/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename, new_folder_name):
return send_from_directory(app.config['/UPLOAD_FOLDER/<new_folder_name>'], filename)
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join the path together yourself, but *sanitize* the folder name first. Reject anything with a path separator in it, for example:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<new_folder_name>/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename, new_folder_name):
    if '/' in filename or '\\' in filename:
        abort(404)
    return send_from_directory(
        os.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], new_folder_name), filename)
```

This creates a new path by using `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` as a base directory, `new_folder_name` as a subfolder and `filename` as the file in that subfolder.

Better still, the `werkzeug` library (underpinning of Flask) comes with a dedicated function that handles all unsafe edgecases, [`werkzeug.security.safe_join()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.security.safe_join):

```
from werkzeug.security import safe_join

@app.route('/uploads/<new_folder_name>/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename, new_folder_name):
    path = safe_join(os.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], new_folder_name)
    if path is None:
        abort(404)
    return send_from_directory(path, filename)
```

If you want to take `filename` from the directory, use:

```
from werkzeug.security import safe_join

@app.route('/uploads/<new_folder_name>/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename, new_folder_name):
    path = safe_join(os.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], new_folder_name)
    if path is None:
        abort(404)
    files = os.listdir(path)
    if not files:
        abort(404)
    return send_from_directory(path, files[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, the URL is made. However when I try to visit it I get a 'not found' error. I expected that if it was non-image file, visiting the URL would just download the file to my HD, but this doesn't seem to be the case, do I need to instantiate this somehow?
I also changed the url_for a bit to only include the folder name and not the filename because this would be messy, is that the case? url_for('uploaded_file', new_folder_name = new_folder_name)
and in my route I only have /<new_folder_name, but the function takes both filename and new_folder_name

Comment: Do you have actual files in that directory? Does printing or returning just `os.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], new_folder_name, filename)` produce a valid path to an existing file?

Comment: Got it working, new problem though. As I said before I don't want the filename itself in the url, just the folder name, but I can't seem to get this working. In my @app.route I only have /<new_folder_name>, but the function attatched to it takes both filename and new_folder_name as parameters. In url_for I have the uploaded file function and new_folder_name=new_folder_name, but when I visit the generated URL I only get the homepage. Doing this with the filename included in url_for works fine. Any way to pass the filename in url_for without it being in the generated url, just the folder name?

Comment: How do you want the filename transferred then? As a query parameter?

Comment: No, I don't want it in the URL at all. There is only going to be one file per subfolder, so if there is a way to do something like send_from_directory, but instead of specifying a filename only specify a directory and have it return all files in that subfolder (which will only be one anyway). If not that, is there a way to generate a URL for the file only using the folder name (this is a shortened UUID) and not the filename?

Comment: You could use `os.listdir()` on the full path and use the first filename in that list as the filename argument, sure.

Comment: [`werkzeug.security.safe_join`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.security.safe_join) is a good alternate for the file checks.

Comment: @user3233758: Added `os.listdir()` to the answer for you as well.